# Running the C++ app from the Eclipse IDE

Tags: c++, eclipse, configuration, output, post-build-event

I am using eclipse IDE. I have here some basic source code including header file. Have been using cygwin as C++ compiler. It compiles my app and it does not produce any error. But I cannot see the output on IDE's console. When I run the executable file on its own it produces output. How to configure Eclipse IDE in order to redirect output to the IDE's console?

This is all I get:

```
15:40:11 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project GetCompiled ****
make all 
Building target: GetCompiled.exe
Invoking: Cygwin C++ Linker
g++  -o "GetCompiled.exe"  ./Compiling.o   
cygwin warning:
  MS-DOS style path detected: D:\Aristotelis\C++\GetCompiled\Debug
  Preferred POSIX equivalent is: /cygdrive/d/Aristotelis/C++/GetCompiled/Debug
  CYGWIN environment variable option "nodosfilewarning" turns off this warning.
  Consult the user's guide for more details about POSIX paths:
    http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html#using-pathnames
Finished building target: GetCompiled.exe


15:40:12 Build Finished (took 702ms)
```

Selected app to run:
[image]

I tried to run the exe file from the IDE by selecting to run as an C++ app, but it does not produce any output.
Best regards

Comment: There are different consoles, check to see which one you're using and try the others.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse/CDT does not automatically run your application after each build. You need to either go trough the menu Run->Open Run->Run or use the keyboard shortcut Crtl+F11, and then check the Console window again.

An advanced feature is to set your application as a **post-build event**. For that, go to your Build Settings and find the appropriate submenu and type the name of your application.exe there (haven't got Eclipse at my fingertips right now). With this setting, the application will be launched automatically after each successful build. This comes in handy if you do **automated unit testing**.

Comment: Yes, I run the app once I build it. Performed the above suggestion, but it does not do any good.

Comment: Do you have CDT installed and are you able to run MinGW instead of Cygwin? The Nuwen distro is particularly well suited for Eclipse on Windows (it already has Boost compiled e.g.), see http://nuwen.net/mingw.html

Comment: As far as I can see CDT has been part of Eclipse; it has some optional selection check-boxes regarding CDT. I have created a new project selecting MinGW, but yet as before no output.